# What is Boolean.valueOf in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, boolean

Typeof of Boolean.valueOf is a function but what does it do? Why object versions of primitives have these methods like Array.valueOf? It's not the same as for example Boolean.prototype.valueOf...

Also what's the point of Boolean.toString() it just returns this: "function Boolean() { [native code] }". Also other objects like Array, Number have it...

Comment: * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean/valueOf
* Array inherits `valueOf` from Object.prototype.
* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/valueOf

MDN: JavaScript calls the `valueOf` method to convert an object to a primitive value. You rarely need to invoke the `valueOf` method yourself; JavaScript automatically invokes it when encountering an object where a primitive value is expected.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Why it happens

`Boolean` is a function, just like `String` and `Object`, you can call it as a function to convert something to a boolean for example:

```
Boolean(3); // true
```

All functions in JavaScript are objects, and as objects they have a `.valueOf` property. Since `Boolean` is a function, its `valueOf` isn't very meaningful though. Since it's calling `Object#valueOf` via prototypical inheritance it just returns the same object

```js
alert(Boolean.valueOf() === Boolean) // true

// for the same reason
var x = {};
alert(x.valueOf() === x); // true
```

The specification states:

> 15.2.4.4 Object.prototype.valueOf
>
> Let O be the result of calling ToObject passing the this value as the argument.

Which in turn does:

> 9.9 ToObject
>
> The result is the input argument (no conversion).

### What it's for

The reason `.valueOf` exists is to provide an interface for explicit value obtaining. It is used extensively in the background of the language (as the other answer mentions, much like `.toString`). For example it can take a `Number` object and convert it into the primitive number data type.

Here is an example:

> 3 == {valueOf: function(){ return 3; }} // true
>
> 4 < {valueOf: function(){ return 2; }} // false
>
> Math.max(3, {valueOf: function(){ return 5; }}) // 5, not the object

It's somewhat incomplete and in all honesty, we don't have a good solution in JavaScript for user defined values until ES7 kicks in with value types.

Comment: Very nice edit! The last example was really interesting

Answer (score 2):

It seems that .valueOf is similar to .toString method according to output.

> JavaScript calls the valueOf method to convert an object to a primitive value. You rarely need to invoke the valueOf method yourself; JavaScript automatically invokes it when encountering an object where a primitive value is expected.
>
> By default, the valueOf method is inherited by every object descended from Object. Every built-in core object overrides this method to return an appropriate value.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf)

Basically .valueOf is used to return primitive version of object, but you don't need to call it yourself. You could use it in your advantage in your library. For example, you have a request object instead of writing your own method, you could extend .valueOf and return status of request.

> Also what's the point of Boolean.toString() it just returns this: "function Boolean() { [native code] }".

I don't sure about Boolean.toString(), but Boolean.prototype.toString() is quite helpful. With .toString method you can get string representation of any object, consider this example:

```
var bool = true;

console.log(bool.toString()); // "true"
```

In some cases it's could be helpful to get string representation of an object, but in most cases JS automatically convert object in string during string concatenation (`+` operator).

More about [.toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString).

Comment: Well said. An interesting observation of `.valueOf` on `Boolean` is that `Boolean === Boolean.valueOf()` is true :)

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that too, in case of primitive JS objects (Array, Number, String, etc.), .valueOf is useless, but using for user defined objects is quite helpful, as the example with request. :)

Comment: Array, Number, String etc are all functions, I'm not sure what you mean by "primitive JS objects"

Comment: They are also constructors too, by primitive objects I meant the core objects of the language like primitives in most of the languages (int, char, long, double, etc.) If you didn't knew, everything is object in JS, even `Function`.

Comment: Oh, you mean primitive value types, those are string, number, boolean, null and undefined. Array is not a primitive value type, you can read more about how types work in the language [here](http://es5.github.io/#x8).

Comment: Yeah, maybe I'm confused array with data type, but others are primitives

Comment: As I learn JavaScript it was my main concern about what people meant writing for example "String", "string" or "_string_", not always mentioning if it's a function object or an instance of a primitive type. Finally I got the difference.